# Spring RestTemplate XML to json

Tags: java, json, xml, resttemplate

```
Original XML file from URL :

<propi tip=ZIP num=103 yr=2019>
    <situation>Stop</situation>
    <id>2210141</id>
    <lastNas>
        <tramit>
            <codOr>186</codOr>
        </tramit
    </lastNas>
    <anda>
        <tramit>
            <codOr>457</codOr>
        </tramit>
        <tramit>
            <codOr>555</codOr>
        </tramit
    </anda>
</propi>
```

---

CODE JAVA:

```
String url = "https://bla bla bla/SiteWS";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

LinkedHashMap<?, ?> object = restTemplate.getForObject(url, LinkedHashMap.class);
```

Object THE RESULT after convert XML :

```
{ {tip=ZIP, num=103, yr=2019, situation=Stop, id=2210141, lastNas={tramit={codOrg=186}}, anda={tramit={codOr=555}}
```

As you can see, i wanna all results from  - ANDA -, but it's only returning single result after converting to JSON. ANY idea?

Comment: because by JSON is a key value pair and when parsing into java it converts into `Map` where old value will be replaced with new value. Why don't you use custom pojo?

Comment: @Deadpool nice one my friend, worked fine with POJO, tyvm.